# How to use Internal Storage of Android in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, storage, internal

I want to be able to use Android's internal storage. I found some code snippets like:

```
 string path = Application.Context.FilesDir.Path;
 var filePath = Path.Combine(path, "test.txt");
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Hello World");
```

But I could not figure out what Application is in here.

Is there any solution for that or different perspective?
Thanks :)

Comment: Application is a static field which refers to your application

Comment: Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).ToString()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "testfile.txt");

// Write
using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
}

// Read
using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename))
{
    string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
}
```

Comment: There isn't any GetFolderPath method in my scope. Could you specify its explicit and thorough scope please?

Comment: Whats your scope? Android Project?

Comment: I want to use it in my Xamarin project's Android part.

Comment: I will. I am dealing with another problems at the moment. I just wanted to inform you :)

Comment: Since this is `Personal` folder you don't.